# Movement Practices in L5R 4e

Tags: movement, l5r-4e

In the movement section of the 4th edition core it states how a Free or Simple action can be used for movement.  Now my big question is, since they separate the concept of a complex action to move as a "special case scenario", but list the maximum movement default as Water x 20', so should a character be allowed to use two simple move actions in a single turn as a difference between walking and running?  Or do they only get one simple action because you can't just move as a complex action for Water x 20' on its own?

Currently I am running it as only being able to do one of the move actions (IE so that the free and simple moves can't be stacked), which leaves it with Water x 10' max movement unless special stuff comes into play.  However, since I predict a chase scene in the next game the ability to double land speed will be vital.

Answer (score 1):

So, I looked this up and here's what I've found. In a normal round you can take either one complex action (Attacks before unlocking the simple action attack option), two simple actions (drawing weapons, moving Water x 10 feet, etc.), and a reasonable number of free actions that I believe cannot be doubled.

Anyway, as for your question, it's perfectly reasonable to take two simple actions to 'double move' for a total of Water x 20 feet, which is the normal maximum movement. I would assume that complex move actions are for things like, I don't know, safely ducking under, leaping over, stepping between a spear gauntlet set up by a rival lord on the way to an objective (the L5R equivalent of a laser hallway). I don't see this coming up a lot though, so it's probably under the GM handwave territory.

Comment: In theory that would qualify as moderate or difficult terrain which would reduce the distance that someone can travel in a single action, or it could be like a certain Earth spell in 3e that inhibits movement to 1ft unless you want to make an Agility roll and risk damage.

Comment: Actually, that's a very good point and it is covered in the rules. So, what would a complex move action be?

Comment: I'd have to thumb through my books, but I imagine it would be linked to a school technique.  Like "as a complex move action, you can keep your previous stealth roll instead of rolling a new one"

Comment: One example is the Centipede Tattoo which is a complex move action to go Water x 100'

Comment: Well that answers that. Thanks CatLord. On a sidenote, Water x 100' Good gravy man!

Comment: It lasts for one day or until you stop for over a minute and then you have to rest 12hrs.  Because it's complex, you can't attack wile you go roadrunner

Comment: Meep meep. Sorry I had to. But yeah, most of my players aren't interested in playing tattooed monks so that may be why I missed it.